# OpenCV - Python Library

Tags: python, opencv, developer-tools

```
 cv.waitKey(1)& 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```

In above code snippet, what is the need of 0xFF ?
If I am not using this in that case also it work fine.

Comment: it's superstition that is propagated through copies of copies of tutorials that never question what they're doing. waitKeyEx returns the full scancode and more flags, waitKey returns fewer bits. masking bits away doesn't do anything useful if you want to react precisely to the Q key and nothing else being pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet posted by you is simply a norm for declaring by which keypress the open-cv window **gets closed** & the script **terminated**.

In that case, it would be the key **'q'** (for quit - as the norm suggests).

Thus your script should work perfectly fine, even if not including the snippet, as it's merely included for terminating the Python script.

Comment: you didn't address the question which was on the purpose of `& 0xFF`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the `& 0xFF` just ensures that whatever value is returned from `cv.waitKey(1)` is in the range of an unsigned byte (in other words, it takes the lowest 8 bits of the return value of `cv.waitKey(1)`).

As long as the value of the last 8 bits of the key you press is within this range `0 <= x <= 255`, the code should work. That being said, I believe it will have a problem if you, hypothetically, pressed a key that has the same lower 8 bits as `'q'`.

So omitting it should be fine.